# how to get Neo4j cluster status using java api

Tags: neo4j, java

I am trying to find the neo4j cluster health using java API. I see CLI CALL dbms.cluster.overview() is there any equivalent java api for this

Answer (score 0):

## 1. Variant "Spring Boot"

If Spring Boot with Spring Data Neo4J is an option for you, you could define a DAO which executes your cypher statement and receives the result in an own QueryResult class.

### 1.1 GeneralQueriesDAO

```
@Repository
public interface GeneralQueriesDAO extends Neo4jRepository<String, Long> {    
    @Query("CALL dbms.cluster.overview() YIELD id, addresses, role, groups, database;")
    ClusterOverviewResult[] getClusterOverview();
}
```

### 1.2 ClusterOverviewResult

```
@QueryResult
public class ClusterOverviewResult {
    private String id;  // This is id of the instance.
    private List<String> addresses; // This is a list of all the addresses for the instance.
    private String role; // This is the role of the instance, which can be LEADER, FOLLOWER, or READ_REPLICA.
    private List<String> groups; // This is a list of all the server groups which an instance is part of.
    private String database; // This is the name of the database which the instance is hosting.

    // omitted default constructor as well getter and setter for clarity    
}
```

### 1.3 Program flow

```
@Autowired
private GeneralQueriesDAO generalQueriesDAO;

[...]

ClusterOverviewResult[] clusterOverviewResult = generalQueriesDAO.getClusterOverview();
```

## 2. Variant "Without Spring"

Without Spring Boot the rough procedure could be:

```
Session session = driver.session();
StatementResult result = session.run("Cypher statement");
```

## 3. Variant "HTTP endpoints"

Another option could be to use of the [HTTP endpoints for monitoring the health of a Neo4j Causal Cluster](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/monitoring/causal-cluster/http-endpoints/#causal-clustering-http-endpoints).